# A weird memory leak problem

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, activex, ocx

I use an ActiveX control which is just a HTTP handler. It sends out an HTTP request, gets the response and fires an event to the user. When the user is not requesting the ActiveX control is pretty much dormant. It just waits for a user request to send another HTTP request.

As long as the window in which the OCX resides does not change (losing focus, getting focus, etc) the memory stays calm. For each of the above said operations I lose approx 400 bytes.

Where should I look for a possible leak?

Comment: Information which you provided is not enough. Please add most detailed description (maybe with parts of code).

Comment: @MSN :-) thanks. One caveat I forgot to mention is in a MFC, C++ app it doesn't leak anymore. But in a .Net C# app it leaks even after the OANCCACHE=1 env variable settings. May be a .Net AxInterop thingy. Using windbg is painfully hard in .Net world to fight leaks :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the HTTP string is passed down via `BSTR`s, you might be running into [`BSTR` caching](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/139071). To verify, you'll want to set the environment variable `OANOCACHE` to 1 or call `OaSetNoCache()` directly. The environment variable should be easier to test with.

Answer (score 0):

Look to off-the-shelf profiling tools that may detect this leak (even debug mode in VC has an option of tracing leaked allocations).